Why doesn't SpaceX use a normal blast trench like Saturn V?
They aimed the engines at the ground, and it dug a huge hole under the launchpad.

Source
So they replaced it with a watercooled steel plate. Why don't they just use a parabolic flame trench like Saturn V?

They had to build big hills at KSC so they could use a trench. Perhaps SpaceX did not want to do that.

Might be worth an edit to make explicit that this question is for Starship, and nothing to do falcon which have their own oddities with handling exhaust during launch.

I think I remember something about the ground water level being too high to simply dig a trench, and as such they'd have to build up, which would make it a lot more costly and would cost a lot more time.

@DaniëlvandenBerg That's the going theory but I don't think there's any official information that would back it up.

I find myself thinking that the flame trench design was adopted so early- mid-50s at Baikonur- that modern engineers might possibly be excused for thinking that it was only used out of habit and that they should possibly try something different.

SpaceX does use flame trenches

Why doesn't Spacex use a normal blast trench like Saturn V?

They do. SpaceX currently has four operational launch pads:

Launch Complex 39A at Kennedy Space Center, Florida
Space Launch Complex 40 at Cape Canaveral Space Force Station, Florida
Space Launch Complex 4 at Vandenberg Space Force Base, California
Orbital Pad A at Starbase, Texas

In addition, they have three more launch pads under construction:

Space Launch Complex 6 at Vandenberg Space Force Base, California
Orbital Pad B at Starbase, Texas
The Starship launch pad at Launch Complex 39A

Of those seven pads, five use a traditional flame trench, one we don't know yet for sure, and one doesn't. So, it is really only one out of seven launch pads that SpaceX doesn't use a traditional flame trench. In fact, SpaceX not only predominantly uses traditional flame trenches "like Saturn V", on LC 39-A, they literally use the Saturn V (and Space Shuttle) flame trench.
The Starship static fire stand at the Massey's Test Site at Starbase also uses a traditional flame trench.
A flame trench does two things
A flame trench does two things:

It increases the distance between the engines and the ground.
It diverts the exhaust of the engines away from the rocket.

A traditional flame trench does those two things by

Digging a big hole underneath the rocket.
Deflecting the exhaust to the side using an angled plate.

But that is not the only way you can do it. For example, at the (now closed) Site 1/5 at Baikonur Cosmodrome, they famously used to just dangle the rocket over a cliff.
If you look at Orbital Pad A at Starbase, that is exactly what SpaceX is doing:

Instead of digging a hole in the ground, they put the rocket on stilts, but the effect is the same: It increases the distance between the engines and the ground.
Instead of using an angled plate, they use high-pressure water, but the effect is the same: It diverts the exhaust of the engines away from the rocket.

So, in some sense, this system does exactly the same thing as a traditional flame trench does.
What happened at Flight 1?
At Flight 1, the steel plate with the water deflector system simply was not ready in time. SpaceX had started building it months before, so they clearly knew it was needed.
However, based on data collected during the multiple static fire tests, they calculated that the pad would survive a single launch. The last static fire before the launch ignited 31 of the 33 Raptor engines on the Super Heavy booster and throttled up to about 50% for several seconds. This caused only minor damage to the top layer of the concrete. Therefore, it was reasonable to conclude that the launch would not cause a total destruction of the launch pad.
So, why did it? Why did SpaceX get it so wrong?
This is exactly the question Dr. Phil Metzger from the Florida Space Institute and formerly of NASA, asked himself, or rather, his students.
Brandon Dotson, a grad student at the Florida Space Institute wrote a paper with Dr. Metzger and others, answering the question: the moist sand in the base layer below the foundations of the launch was superheated which caused the water to flash-boil into a steam explosion. In other words, a giant bomb went off under the launch pad … which is the wrong way round from how the launch pad is designed to work!
The paper is titled A new launch pad failure mode: Analysis of fine particles from the launch of the first Starship orbital test flight by B. Dotson, P. Metzger, J. Hafner, A. Shackelford, K. Birkenfeld, D. Britt, A. Ford, R. Truscott, S. Truscott, J. Zavaleta, J. Zemke, K. Purvis, M. Scudder, C. Johnson, J. Galloway, J. DeShetler. Here is the most important sentence from the abstract [bold italic emphasis mine]:

This study […] suggests a new launch pad failure mode previously unknown.

So, in other words: nobody had seen, or written about something like this ever before. Therefore, I think we can cut SpaceX some slack for not foreseeing something that even the people who study how to land rockets on unprepared surfaces on the Moon and on Mars never had thought of before.

Very interesting salient information about the Starship 1 failure mode!

I'm not so sure they couldn't've predicted this; sure, this particular failure mode hadn't happened to a rocket launchpad before, but steam explosions from introducing damp-or-wet things to lots of heat're as old as the Industrial Revolution.  Couldn't someone have put two and two together and realized that placing a launchpad directly over moist ground without anything to buffer or deflect the rocket exhaust wouldn't be a great idea?

@Vikki that would require modelling the thermodynamics of the launch pad and supporting ground layers. Given that SpaceX objects to basic principles like protecting local native species, it is clear that some things have much lower priority than others. In the "move fast and break things" philosophy, you conduct a minimal test to demonstrate the plan you have in mind, and then extrapolate with the understanding that you will discover new failure modes along the way. So yes, they could have anticipated it, but chose not to.

Interesting about the water deflecting the exhaust. I had thought of it as the steel plate diverting the exhaust, just in all directions not a specific one, and that the water just absorbed much of the energy. But I guess the sideways motion of the water can also direct the exhaust somewhat, I just wonder by how much. And the water presumably helps block any portion of the exhaust that is reflecting back up at the rocket.

"Given that SpaceX objects to basic principles like protecting local native species"  [citation needed]

SpaceX (the company) uses the same flame trench that the Saturn V used when they launch Falcon 9 and Falcon Heavy rockets from pad 39A at Kennedy Space Center.

2015 rendering of future Falcon 9 at pad 39A launch facility (SpaceX)

SpaceX Falcon 9 launches at SLC-40 at Cape Canaveral Space Force Station also use a traditional flame trench.

First Falcon 9 on pad SLC-40, one year before its 2010 launch debut (SpaceX)

SpaceX Falcon 9 launches at SLC-4 at Vandenberg Space Force Base use a traditional flame trench.

Falcon 9 on pad SLC-4, June 2019 (SpaceX)
SpaceX is using the original flame trench at pad 39A used by the Saturn V and later Space Shuttle launches. I am not sure if SpaceX built the flame trenches at the SLC-40 and SLC-4 launch sites or if they are using the existing flame trenches that were used by previous rockets at those sites.
For Starship launches, SpaceX planned to install a concrete foundation covered by a steel plate which has a built-in water deluge system that would spray a powerful blast of water underneath the rocket at liftoff.

Starship water deluge (low pressure) initial test, July 2023 (SpaceX)
Reportedly due to Elon Musk's anxiousness to get the first Starship test launch conducted in order to gather data, it was decided to not wait for the water deluge system to be installed. However they did not just "aim the engines at the ground", they installed a thick layer of heat resistant Fondag concrete underneath the rocket, hoping to at least minimize damage to the rocket and the launch structure. The concrete proved inadequate, leading to the crater that you showed in your question during the first Starship test flight in April 2023, as well as a number of damaged parts of the launch pad that had to be repaired.
Elon Musk explained the decision the next day in a post on X:

3 months ago, we started building a massive water-cooled, steel plate to go under the launch mount. Wasn’t ready in time & we wrongly thought, based on static fire data, that Fondag would make it through 1 launch.

The new water deluge system was in place for the second Starship test flight in November 2023, as well as the third and fourth test flights. Damage to the launch pad was greatly minimized, although some repairs have been needed after each launch.
In 2024 SpaceX installed a more traditional flame trench at its nearby Massey test site, which is used for static fire testing of the Starship orbital stage.

Starship static fire tests at Massey test site (S.E. Robinson, Jr.)
SpaceX appears to be planning to install a more traditional flame trench at its second Boca Chica Starship launch pad currently under construction. Independent observations have noted concrete work at the new pad which is consistent with a traditional flame trench. As mentioned in another answer Elon confirmed this in an interview with Tim Dodd in June 2024. However as far as I know SpaceX has not yet confirmed the reason for this change. It's possible that it was decided that the steel plate water deluge system, while effective, was not fully adequate. Or it's possible that the specific location of the second launch pad requires the exhaust to be more directed, instead of going in all directions like it does at the current launch pad. More information will likely be forthcoming from SpaceX about the new launch pad as it gets closer to completion and first launch. It is also not known if the first launch pad will eventually be retrofitted with a flame trench. Likely this would depend on the results of test flights at the new pad.

It may have to do with lawsuits and bad press due to environmental effects of previous launches (Wikipedia mentions this). In addition SpaceX has been accused of planning expanded operations at Boca Chica that were not included in the original impact plan.

That's possible, although SpaceX normally seems to follow the ask forgiveness not permission principle. Knowing the "why" part of their decisions is often elusive unless Elon chooses to give a reason. I am guessing that the water cooled steel plate experiment showed that it can be done, but that even with further refinements it would never work as well as a flame trench, and the cost and complexity of this method were possibly more than they expected. They may also have realized that they will need a flame trench at 39A, and so wanted to try it out here first.

They didn't add a flame trench because they thought they might be able to get away without one. Building a flame trench is a big undertaking, you either need to dig deep (tricky in marshy ground, close to the sea, with a high water table) or build a hill to put the launch mount on (expensive). It's much simpler and cheaper to put the launch mount on long legs and use strong concrete underneath.
SpaceX like to challenge conventional wisdom, rockets have always used flame trenches but what if, with modern concretes, they're no longer necessary? The only way to find out is to try.
However all through starship testing the concrete wasn't able to withstand the thrust. There were some improvements but ultimately the concrete completely failed during IFT 1. Adding the deluge system is about the best they could probably do without completely rebuilding the whole launch stand.
It sounds like there are some plans for some form of trench for the second launch mount




Tim: It'll have more of a flame trench this time?
Elon: Yeah


Note that construction of the water deflector / steel plate system started long before Flight 1, so it's not like SpaceX were caught totally unaware. They just didn't expect it to be this bad, and they had no reason to: the static fire tests at 50% throttle and shorter times only caused minor damage, so you could expect the launch to cause major damage but not the complete and utter destruction. Scientists wrote a paper on what happened, and they concluded that this particular failure mode was previously unknown, so we can't fault SpaceX for overlooking it.

"you either need to dig deep (tricky in marshy ground, close to the sea, with a high water table)" - Isn't water coming in a good thing in this particular use case?

@Vikki not in an uncontrolled manner. Filling the trench with water would turn it from a trench into a pond and there wouldn't be anywhere for the exhaust to go

@AlanBirtles Also, salt water is really not something you want to be using for your cooling system.

worse than just expensive, the ground may simply not have been able to support the sheer weight of a proper flame trench built up on top of it out of aggregate and concrete. Digging into it I know was out of the question because of the very high water table (they'd be digging in soft mud and clay).

@Vikki not if you want to stabilise the ground in order to build it into something you can control. You want water where and when you need it, and only where and when you need it.
